# How to copy chunks of text at regular intervals from one text file to another

Tags: text, batch-processing

I have a text (XML) file with chunks of data (each 16 lines in length) separated by the string /scan. I need to copy every 5th chunk of data, including the preceding /scan string, into a new file essentially turning my one text file into 5 new files where each file contains 1/5 of the data. I have a variety of languages available (linux, python, R, etc) and I am open to options. For example given the text:

/scan

```
chunk 1
```

/scan

```
chunk 2
```

/scan

```
chunk 3
```

/scan

```
chunk 4
```

/scan

```
chunk 5
```

/scan

```
chunk 6
```

/scan

```
chunk 7
```

/scan

```
chunk 8
```

/scan

```
chunk 9
```

/scan

```
chunk 10
```

The resulting files would contain:

File 1:

/scan

```
chunk 1
```

/scan

```
chunk 6
```

File 2:

/scan

```
chunk 2
```

/scan

```
chunk 7
```

File 3:

/scan

```
chunk 3
```

/scan

```
chunk 8
```

...and so on.

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO Off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "destdir=U:\destdir"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q35757136.txt"
SET "outfile=%destdir%\q35757136_out"
SET /a outfiles=5
SET /a outnum=0
:: delete existing output files
FOR /L %%a IN (1,1,%outfiles%) DO DEL "%outfile%%%a.txt" >NUL 2>nul
FOR /f "usebackqdelims=" %%a IN ("%filename1%") DO (
 IF "%%a"=="/scan" SET /a outnum=1+(outnum %% %outfiles%^)
 >>"%outfile%!outnum!" ECHO(%%a
)

GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the settings of `sourcedir` and `destdir` to suit your circumstances.

I used a file named `q35757136.txt` containing your data for my testing.

Produces the files defined as %outfile%+*anumber*.txt

For each line of input, see whether it is the key string. If it is, increment the output file selector.

reproduce each line to the selected output file.

Assumes OP is aware of the shortcomings of batch string-processing.